# How to create an unprivileged user in CentOS?

Tags: centos, users, init-script, privileges

I want to create an unprivileged user to run my RhodeCode server and Celery daemon on a CentOS instance.  I think the accepted definition of this is no home directory, login disabled, and no shell access?  Looking over the man page for adduser I just don't see an intuitive method for doing this.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-users-add.html) (centos.org)

`useradd` (which is the actual binary the runs when you call adduser, it just behaves differently. See [here](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2008-November/068320.html) about that.) has an flag `-r` which is documented as follows:

```
-r   Create a system account with a UID less than 500 and without a home directory
```

Which sounds like what you want to do.

Comment: Interestingly, at least on Redhat `/etc/passwd` will have a home directory entry (`/home/username` by default); the directory, of course, won't exist, but that's kinda strange )

Answer (score 16):

I think I should link here two answers from *serverfault*:

- [how do i duplicate the nobody user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/240470/how-do-i-duplicate-the-nobody-user)
  and
- [Create restricted user on Debian server](https://serverfault.com/a/430463/102099)
  ( btw, it was moved to serverfault from *stackoverflow*, just recently -- and possibly could have been moved to this site as well )

Basically `-r` means "set account as a system one" -- "no expiration", etc -- and the full spell may look like

```
useradd -s /bin/false -r <username>
```

or

```
useradd -s /usr/sbin/nologin -r -M -d /dev/null <username>
```

or similar )

NB. For things like samba one may also want to provide this user with a password and may be also add `/usr/sbin/nologin` to `/etc/shells` :

```
# which nologin >> /etc/shells
```

NB(2): as per OrangeDog's comment: `-r` actually implies `-M`, so `-M` is not strictly necessary.

PS. And yes, looking for the same thing at *serverfault*, *askubuntu* -- and here -- seems a bit odd to me; is there a way to run a meta-search on, say, *all* stackoverflow sites ?

Comment: As for meta-search -- any "native" option is missing for the moment, but there is [custom Google search for stack exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59900/cross-stack-exchange-search?rq=1)

Comment: I've seen services like named using `/sbin/nologin` in `/etc/passwd`. So how do they start their services?

Comment: @OrangeDog: I don't have a CentOS system at my disposal right now, but on both Redhat and Debian `-d` is not ignored; it is strange that none of the reviewers had actually bothered to test )

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `-r` option.

Comment: I just created a user using `adduser -s /sbin/nologin -M rhodecode`, but the -r option does seem to be what I'm looking for.  What is the difference between using -r and what I did?  I'm a shell scripting noob, sorry.

Comment: I recommend you look at the `useradd(8)` man page to see how it affects the user created.